# How to navigate to route of another component in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, here is my case:

I have a app.js, which is a parent component of categories.js, and nav.js

```
  return (
      <Router>
      ...
      ...
      <header>
          <div className="navbar">
            <Nav
                userData={userData}
            />
          </div>
      </header>
      .....
        <div className="row">
            <div className="categories col-lg-10 col-md-12">
              <Categories
                  setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}
              />
            </div>
      .....
```

Categories.js, i can access the url enter the access like this https://localhost:3000/posts/123/page/1

```
 return (
        <div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/posts/:postId/page/:page" element={<OpenPostsOverlayByRoute setIsRoute={setIsRoute} />} />
            </Routes>
         ......
```

Nav.js

```
return (

    ..........
    
                                <div className="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                                    <div
                                        className={`tab-pane fade ${activeTab === 'home' ? 'show active' : ''}`}
                                        id="home"
                                        role="tabpanel"
                                        aria-labelledby="home-tab"
                                    >
                                        {/* Home tab content */}
                                        {nav1 && (
                                            <Nav1
                                                userData={userData}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    </div>
    ...........
```

Nav1.js

```
const openOverlay = (postId, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    navigate(`/posts/${postId}/page/${page}`);
    //navigate("/");
}

return (
    <>
        <div className="Nav1" ref={containerRef} style={{ overflowY: 'scroll', height: '400px' }}>
            {/* Render the results */}
            <ul>
                {results.map((result) => (
                    <li key={result.notify_id}><a href="#" onClick={(event) => openOverlay(result.post_id, event)}>{result.title}</a></li>
                ))}
            </ul>

            {/* Render a loading indicator while fetching */}
            {isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
            {!hasMore && <p>No more results</p>} {/* Display a message when there are no more results */}
        </div>
    </>
);
```

is it possible to navigate to https://localhost:3000/posts/123/page/1 the routes defined in categories.js from nav1.js? Or i need to re-construct the code entirely?

Comment: What you're asking is not clear, is there something specific in the snippets you've shared that does not work, or you'd like to do "better"?